# Azure Marketplace SaaS fulfilment API- resolving subscription - PHP

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to resolve an azure marketplace subscription using the azure fulfilment api. I have followed the instructions on the Microsoft's SaaS fulfilment api's docs but I am not able to resolve the subscription using PHP.
I am able to get access_token and incidentally I am able to use the token and and use this together with the purchase identification token i get from azure portal when the subscriber is re-directed to the SaaS landing page, to get a successful json response when using postman.
I cannot achieve the same success when using PHP. I get a 403 error - Authorization is missing, incorrect or invalid. I am thinking that the query string bit of authorization parameter is malformed. This has nothing to do with privileges or permissions as I am able to get a successful output on Postman. Here is the code

```
<?php
 use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
 use Microsoft\Graph\Http;
 use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;

 class GraphHelper {
private static Client $tokenClient;
private static Client $tokenWebClient;
private static string $clientId = '';
private static string $tenantId = '';
private static string $clientSec = '';
private static string $graphUserScopes = '';
private static Graph $userClient;
private static string $userToken;
private static string $resolveToken;
private static string $subToken= '';

public static function initializeGraphForUserAuth(): void {
    GraphHelper::$tokenClient = new Client();
    GraphHelper::$clientId = $_ENV['CLIENT_ID'];
    GraphHelper::$clientSec = $_ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'];
    GraphHelper::$tenantId = $_ENV['TENANT_ID'];
    GraphHelper::$graphUserScopes = $_ENV['GRAPH_USER_SCOPES'];
    GraphHelper::$userClient = new Graph();
    
}
public static function getUserToken(): void {
//getting the access token 
    $accessCodeRequestUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.GraphHelper::$tenantId.'/oauth2/token';
    $tokenRequestUrl = 'https://marketplaceapi.microsoft.com/api/saas/subscriptions/resolve?api-version=2018-08-31';
    $subToken = $_SESSION['subToken'];
  $tokenResponse = GraphHelper::$tokenClient->post($accessCodeRequestUrl, [
        'form_params' => [
            'client_id' =>  GraphHelper::$clientId,
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_secret' => GraphHelper::$clientSec,
            'resource' => '20e940b3-4c77-4b0b-9a53-9e16a1b010a7'
        ],
        // These options are needed to enable getting
            // the response body from a 4xx response
            'http_errors' => false,
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => false
            ]
    ]);
        if ($tokenResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Return the access_token
            $responseBody = json_decode($tokenResponse->getBody()->getContents());
            GraphHelper::$resolveToken = $responseBody->access_token;
            $resolveAccessToken= $responseBody->access_token;
        } else if ($tokenResponse->getStatusCode() == 400) {
            // Check the error in the response body
            $responseBody = json_decode($tokenResponse->getBody()->getContents());
            if (isset($responseBody->error)) {
                $error = $responseBody->error;
                // authorization_pending means we should keep polling
                if (strcmp($error, 'authorization_pending') != 0) {
                    throw new Exception('Token endpoint returned '.$error, 100);
                }
            }
        }

//resolving the subscription
    

 $resolveResponse = GraphHelper::$tokenClient->post($tokenRequestUrl, [
            'form_params' => [
                'content-type' => 'application/json', 
                
                'authorization' =>   'Bearer '.$resolveAccessToken,
            'x-ms-marketplace-token'=> $subToken
            ],
            // These options are needed to enable getting
            // the response body from a 4xx response
            'http_errors' => false,
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => false
            ]
        ]);

//test whether there is a reponse 
return  $resolveResponse->getStatusCode(); // this returns a 403 - Authorization is missing, incorrect or invalid.
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to use cUrl for option to include authorization and other headers. Postman did this automatically hence the reason I was able to get results with postman and not with PHP. Eventually this code did it for me.

```
$subToken = rawurldecode($_SESSION['subToken']);
    $ch = curl_init ();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenRequestUrl);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Authorization: Bearer '.GraphHelper::$resolveToken,

                                        'Content-type: application/json',
                                        'X-ms-marketplace-token:'. $subToken));
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   

 $results =  json_decode (curl_exec ($ch), 1);
 if (array_key_exists ('error', $results)){  

 echo ($results['error']);    

 die();

}
        curl_close($ch);
        return $results['subscriptionName'] ;
```

I found out that the endpoint was not accepting a get request. It threw an error of `Subscription resolve not found","target":"subscriptionId","code":"EntityNotFound` . However including a post option corrected that and no error was thrown after this. Again when decoding the token from the url - don't use `urldecode()` use `rawurldecode ()` instead.